# How can I make an expensive methods data available to all webapi requests without reducing performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have some data that needs to be lazily accessed once my WebApi Controller Method gets called (data is processed by GetModelRelationalInformation() method, and is potentially an expensive operation, that once created exists for the life of the service, the rest of the service is very quick, but the result can't be cached due to other parameters being passed in).
I wanted to avoid using a full caching library or a singleton, so thought making use of the application variable would be the way forward:

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Application["ModelRelationalInfo"] == null)
 {
     HttpContext.Current.Applicatin["ModelRelationalInfo"] = GetModelRelationalInformation();
 }
 return HttpContext.Current.Applicatin["ModelRelationalInfo"];
```

However, if a second request comes in before the data is built, I don't want the expensive method to run again, so I'm considering adding a lock around this like so:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Application["ModelRelationalInfo"] == null)
{
    lock (padlock)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Application["ModelRelationalInfo"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Applicatin["ModelRelationalInfo"] = GetModelRelationalInformation();
        }
    }
}
return HttpContext.Current.Applicatin["ModelRelationalInfo"];
```

I know locks are expensive, but this should only matter for initial requests to the service (those that come in while the data is being built). 
Is it safe to access the application variable in this way? - are there alternatives approaches we should consider such as a singleton being more appropriate?

This is part of a much bigger service, so putting this into global.asax would increase the startup time of the service, which I also want to avoid.

EDIT: note that padlock is a class member static variable in the same method as this code.

Comment: Note: Apologies in advance if this should be on code review, I wasn't sure, I'm not asking for a code review - it is a specific programming problem, but it is a working piece of code and the question does relate to Best practices and design pattern usage, Performance and Correctness in unanticipated cases.

Comment: Locking is essential in this situation, but be careful. The `padlock` should be static and available globally.

Comment: @Salar thanks - padlock is a read-only static variable that exists in the class this method is in.

Comment: Have you tested concurrent requests and noticed slow performance? If so, try first to optimize your GetModelRelationalInformation method at the database level (if applicable) then try using .NET concurrent collections already out there. Also, if I'm not wrong, caching isn't as useful here since parameters are changed and caching can add a bit of overhead.

Comment: @IslamYahiatene we used loader.io and it seemed alright, though I can't tell how much overhead this actually adds when doing this without the lock.

Comment: Since everything is in order then do not try to introduce any changes that might add unnecessary overhead later until needed.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use a caching mechanism. Just take a look at System.Web.Caching.

For your question, you can also use Lazy<> class. This is the recommended way of these kind of operations.

Comment: will have a look at system.web.caching, is there an advantage or is this just personal preference?

Comment: You can invalidate or set an expiration time to your cached objects. It might be better than storing in a static object for some situations. Cache objects generally have weak references. So you could have slightly low chance of memory leak problems.

Comment: sure. in this case that isn't required, this data is built once from a verity of sources, mashed together and then doesn't expire until the service is reloaded (it might change a few times a year).